# which data structure to choose for ip datagram reassembly at receiver end?

Tags: networking, data-structures, ip, ipv4, ip-fragmentation

While reassembling datagram at receiver which data structure would be better in terms of

1. if 1-2 fragment got lost we should discard complete datagram
2. sorting of fragments should be faster
3. if fragments are further fragmented then reassembling all should be smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: Array, usually termed as Buffer.

**Long answer**:

You can read [RFC 791](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekolq.png) for all the details.

1. Apparently, you can start reading from [Page 24] "Fragmentation and Reassembly". You don't sort. Sorting is costly. You do some math and put the fragments in the right place instead.

[Page 28] mentions the Reassembly Procedure:

[image]

2. I had earlier worked with [Contiki OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiki). You can [see how a buffer is declared and used](https://dak664.github.io/contiki-doxygen/a00091.html) there.
3. You can also have some fun going through Google's [Efficient IP datagram reassembly](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20030056009) patent.

Comment: 1 question here, while reassembling if some fragment gets lost OR is delayed then how do we handle that case? Say in our buffer there are 2-3 fragmented sets while processing 1 we found that some of the fragment is missing, should we straight away discard it and go ahead with other fragment or wait for some timer. I had a look at your implementation but couldn't see anything related to this. Thanks

Comment: @anand Do you have any case which line 18 or 19 `timer expires` doesn't handle?